# $A \subseteq C$ if and only if $A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show and Prove that: $$A \subseteq C \leftrightarrow A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap C$$

where $\leftrightarrow$ is a double implication

Comment: When asking a question on Math.SE, tell the readers what you have already tried (also, make sure to try).

Comment: Par34. Desde el titulo sabes de que va a tratar el problema, tienes la libertad de pasarlo por alto, Math SE. se trata de resolver problemas, no de complicarlos. OK.

Comment: First off, I do not speak Spanish. Second off, after having translated your message, I can tell you that this is not the culture of Math.SE, and it's also why your question was both down-voted and closed.

Comment: El cultura es de *ayudarte* resolver a la problema, no dar la solución solamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A \subseteq C$. Then

$$A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C) = (A \cup B) \cap C$$

Conversely, suppose 
$$A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap C$$

Let $x \in A$. Then by the above equality, we have that $x \in (A\cup B) \cap C$. Therefore, $x \in C$.

Answer (score 1):

By the distributive law, $A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$. If $A\subseteq C$, then $A\cup C=C$ and hence $A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap C$.

This proves the forward ($\rightarrow$) direction. Can you try the other direction?